# scrapy python take out URLs from class name

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new in scrapy

I would like to take all URLs from the class, for instance I have this code

```
#i did something like this but i did not work
myURLs = []
class CoolSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'cool'
allowed_domains = ['phooky.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.phooky.com/']
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_obj", follow=True),)

def parse_obj(self, response):
    item = response.url
    myURLs.append(item)
    print(item)
```

then finally when I put print(myURLs), nothing is showing
of course i run this in the command line

Thank you all

Comment: Where did you put `print(myURLs)`? I imagine if you put it in `parse_obj` it will print the whole list as it grows.